# Manager not happy that I have discussions with executives at events and following up in emails

Tags: management, email, teamwork

**Situation:**

- At our monthly events I socialized with leadership (executives) and had an "elevator pitch" with the outcome of executives' support on a critical project for the organization and with a request to hear the outcome of a presentation by xyz date. Our leadership is present at this meeting to encourage interaction and all are considered as "one team".

**Actions:**

- Did send the requested email out following xyz date with all being asked, the next steps in the process, and my vision on the power of the project. And thank you for the help offered along the way + thank you statement for our fruitful discussion. On top of all pointed to my direct reporting manager that I spoke with executives who are willing to help with the project and to find out more about it. **Note:** I'm getting fairly easy along with any chain of command and can conduct a fruitful conversation but my manager blocks me all the time on "shining" and is very intrusive in silencing me from interacting with anyone from anyone from our organization except my teammates. It is to be noted that the executive didn't point in our conversation that I should "run by my manager my discussion and vision" and all this was at an event where nobody else from my team or manager bothered to attend to have interaction.

**Outcome:** My follow-up email was just a thank you + the summary did shake ground for my reporting manager. Also, executives looped his team of directors to help, excluding my direct reporting manager.
All directors and executives are very thankful for the summary and for the follow-up email and very supportive except my manager because right away scheduled a meeting to point out that **"I should not speak or interact without first vetting any conversation I do have planned"** and that is a chain of command and made my manager look bad that I caught the attention and had a conversation with executives (is a large corporation). I clearly stated that no complaints and no feedback on the project were given and was a simple summary of a paper, simply a requested follow-up outcome feedback + thank you.
In my opinion, in general would look bad if after having a conversation for couple of times to not reply with the requested info and thanking for their conversation time. I do interact on all meetings and multiple occasions with leadership and never in my life had been pointed to me to be silent and not speak + if anything I want to communicate to let the manager first know and forward to the appropriate person.

> **Ask:** Why would my manager be concerned about me interacting with leadership when our organization does encourage and make events especially for us willing to spare time and conduct conversations with leadership directly? Why is my manager considering that I did break the chain of command for having interaction with leadership? Are those events meant for us to stay silent and avoid leadership? Why am I being heard by leadership but my manager wants to silence me and not let me speak without his permission? Did I do wrong here for interacting with leadership?
> How should I deal with this situation? I clearly state that: *I do
> not see anything wrong being done and was not, in any case, an escalation, per se, as can be seen in the email forwarded by directors*. Are not managers to facilitate interactions, support, and growth?

**Update:** more details on “shining”: By not offering a platform for presenting the work I do need to do a lot of “catch up” and explaining in detail and later finding out that all had been presented in meetings and internal forums by himself or a person from the team “trusted” by himself. I asked already the whys and have been told that I’m not skilled with the leading part. It all started when the current manager joined our team and we had a meeting with his director(a director who wanted me on the team). On top of all, anything that's presented to leadership is checked for accuracy with me but I’m excluded from meetings and am just brought in a colleague to get credit for, and during all meetings, I'm called or IM for any questions that the audience has, and more situations ...

Thank you for your help.

*Sorry for the spelling, will bring GPT for rewriting soon ...*

Comment: What does this mean? : my manager blocks me all the time on "shining"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There can be two things at play here.

- First (which is most likely), is that, your manager does not need you to take "permission", rather they need to be "informed". The effort you are putting, should be accounted for, and since they are responsible for your time and efforts, they need to know that if you are putting effort on something, that is also aligned with their targets and goals. If, by trying to contribute to this "improvement" task, you somehow fail to deliver on your assigned tasks, eventually they'll be responsible - so they need to kow what are the activities you are getting engaged into. Keep them posted, and you should be good.
- Second (least likely, but still possible) - they feel threatened about their position and authority, and actively trying to prevent you from having a direct communication channel. They are concerned about their job security, and somehow want to take credit for the ideas / work / efforts. If this happens to be the case (i.e., the conflict continues even after following the advise on first point above) - please find a new manager to work for.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that it's more the reverse that's true, and that the manager is more likely threatened by the fact someone "beneath" them is having better discussions with the executives and that they fear they would be overlooked by OP for promotions and credit

Comment: @Harrison I had the same understanding for about first ~15 years of my career, but then, I realised it's more about point 1, and some people are horrible at expressing the actual reasoning behind a(ny) ask.

Answer (score 3):

### What if your boss has a point?

Partial answer, you have one good answer already but it doesn't cover an important aspect: Your manager might be the manager for a reason. He may know the ley of the land and he may worry about all the potential downsides. **He is left out of the loop and you do not have the information he has.** He knows the resouce allocation of the team, he knows what has to be stopped for something else to start, he knows the team and what they are capable of. He knows you and what you are capable of. He knows way better than you the political climate and the political season in the company. Is this the right time for project XY? Are top managers looking for a sacrificial lamb? A token project? Who can be trusted? Who are shifty? Who are yes-people, who are the no-people?

IF you go past your manager, at your own peril it is. The nail that sticks out gets hammered down, most often. But of course, with risk comes the chance of reward, I had a colleague who got promoted 3x by just starting to report his project to the CEO. The CEO took an interest and suddenly my colleague was working directly for the C-suites.